# Find the value of $\cos 1^\circ + \cos 2^\circ + \cos 3^\circ +.....+\cos 180^\circ $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the value of $\cos 1^\circ + \cos 2^\circ + \cos 3^\circ +.....+\cos 180^\circ $

My Attempt:
$$=\cos 1^\circ + \cos 2^\circ + \cos 3^\circ +....+\cos 180^\circ $$
$$= \cos 1^\circ + \cos 2^\circ + \cos 3^\circ +....-1$$

How do I complete it?

Comment: If $x+y=180^\circ$, what can you say about $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(y)$.  More specifically, can you relate $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(180^\circ - x)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, How does that question relate to mine?

Comment: Just do it. What is $\cos(180-x)+\cos(x)$?

Comment: @JohnLou, $\cos (180-x)+\cos x=0$.

Comment: Exactly :) How can you write your equation in terms of sets of those?

Comment: @amWhy, isn't the second one with $\sin$ instead of $\cos$? That makes a pretty big difference, I think.

Comment: @JohnLou  Yes!! you're right, now removed.  Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @JohnLou, No idea. would you please tell?

Comment: @Albert, can't u see the relationship?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, No.. sorry..sir i can't.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer this question anymore, so I'm just gonna write it here because it seems like you need it.

Your question is equal to 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{89}(\cos(k)) + \cos(90)+ \sum_{k=91}^{179}(\cos(k)) + \cos(180)$$

Simplifying down, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{89}(\cos(k) + \cos(180-k)) + \cos(90) + \cos(180)$$

Notice how the summation now cancels to zero, leaving us with 
$$\cos(90) + \cos(180) = 0 + -1 = -1$$

Comment: @JohnLou, How did you get the step after " Simplifying down, we get" ?

Comment: Well, look at the two summations. The first term in the first is $1$, the last in the second summation is $179$. $1+179 = 180$. The last term in the first is $89$, the first in the last is $91$. $89+91 = 180$. Therefore, we can see that they are all paired and sum up to 180.